# Can't set virtualenv - problem with source activation.ps1

Tags: python, django, windows, virtualenv

Fallowing the freecodecamp's django tutorial I'm stack on the very beginning - I can't set up virtualenv. Everything goes great until it's time to make final step - activate virtualenv and download Django.

I'm working on Windows 10, and tried a lot of ways to solve it. Everything ends up with to results, but first things first. Here is what i did:

- Ran powershell as administrator and set up ExecutionsPolicy as unrestricted
- Create new folder called 'Dev'
- Inside Dev created another folder for project with virtualenv - everything by command 'virtualenv name of the folder
- Tried to activate it by "name_of_project's_folder\Scripts\activate"

After this I'm getting error which says that I must "source this script". I tried to make path to the Scripts folder and type only activate but it doesn't work. When I tried to type "name_of_project's_folder\Scripts\activate" but with ".bat" added on the end, nothing happens. Like, literally nothing.

I really hope for making this work because I'm slowly getting frustrated coz of tons of research I made today nad a lot of blind tries to solve this. Python was downloaded via powershell and pip if it's important.

Answer (score 0):

What about project_folder\Scripts\activate.ps1? Or you can just use cmd instead of powershell.

Comment: I'm using powershell and adding an extention "ps1" couses request of source that script